# TYPO3 8.7.x Extbase: Indexed_search indexing not working for own extension

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

I've created a simple extbase/fluid based news extension with a listview showing the latest news. I'm also using indexed_search to search the whole website. The problem is, that the indexed_search not indexing any words of my news.

How can I use indexed_search for my own extension?
I can't find anything helpful on the web for hours. I would be very thankful for every hint or keyword.
Fluid template of the listview of my extension:

```
<f:for each="{berichts}" as="bericht">
        <div class="bericht">
            <div class="bericht_titel">
                <h1>
                    <b>[<f:for each="{bericht.kategorien}" as="kategorie" iteration="i">{kategorie.name}<f:if condition="{i.isLast}"><f:then></f:then><f:else>, </f:else></f:if></f:for>]</b>&nbsp;<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="65" format="html" arguments="{bericht: bericht}">{bericht.titel}</f:link.action>
                </h1>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
            <div class="bericht_text">
                <f:if condition="{bericht.bild}">
                    <a href="{f:uri.image(src: bericht.bild.originalResource.publicUrl)}" class="bericht_bild"><f:image image="{bericht.bild}" alt="" /></a>
                </f:if>
                <f:format.html>{bericht.text}</f:format.html>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <f:if condition="{bericht.anhaenge}">
                    <div class="bericht_anhang">
                        <b>Anhänge:</b><br />
                        <f:for each="{bericht.anhaenge}" as="anhang">
                            <div>
                                <a href="{anhang.originalResource.publicUrl}" target="_blank">
                                    <f:if condition="{anhang.originalResource.title}">
                                        <f:then>
                                            {anhang.originalResource.title}
                                        </f:then>
                                        <f:else>
                                            {anhang.originalResource.originalFile.name}
                                        </f:else>
                                    </f:if>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </f:for>
                    </div>
                </f:if>
            </div>
        </div>
</f:for>
```

Generated HTML of one "Bericht"

```
<div class="bericht">
    <div class="bericht_titel">
        <h1><b>[Allgemeines]</b>&nbsp;<a href="/aktuelles/bericht/?tx_companyaktuelles_p1aktuelles%5Bbericht%5D=3&amp;amp;tx_companyaktuelles_p1aktuelles%5Baction%5D=show&amp;amp;tx_companyaktuelles_p1aktuelles%5Bcontroller%5D=Bericht&amp;amp;tx_companyaktuelles_p1aktuelles%5Bformat%5D=html&amp;amp;cHash=d6c3c8ef294eee899bc15150443b0775">Test</a></h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true" style="transform: rotate(90deg);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bericht_text" style="display: block;">
        <p>Dies ist ein Test</p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is your extension output cached (indexed_search only indexes cached content)? this also means: don't call your page with BE-login and expect a filling of the index, as there will not be any caching while you are logged in in the BE. and last: is your content inside the appropiate markers?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ my content is within the markers <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--><!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->. Normal content could be found. In my extension I only defined cachable actions (configurePlugin) If that is enough to active caching?

Comment: I also called the page without logged in in the BE.

Comment: you might need to use cHash parameter to verify your parameters. Are cHash paramters in the generated URLs (if you deactivate realurl)?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I'm not using a single view, only listview. So, I don't need cHash parameters?

Comment: cHash is used to verify and validate your URL-parameters. if you have no detail-pages, maybe a pagination? other attempt: do you have your action declared as non-cachable? (look into your `ext_localconf.php`, search for `configurePlugin()`)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I'm using dropdown boxes to show the full context. But the at least the title should be found. The non-cachable parameter od the configurePlugin method is an emty array []. Now for testing, I added a single view, but the indexed_search still found nothing. :(

Comment: can you add the html-source of your page to your question? (you may remove header and footer)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I added the fluid template of the listview

Comment: the fluid-template looks ok, therefore a view to the generated HTML in context of the page might reveal more.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I added the generated html of one item. Don't know why the link is generated wrong.

Comment: The double encoded ampersand seems to be a realurl problem.

Comment: the context can't be seen as you only showed the code of your plugin. whether the double encoded ampersand is a bug of realurl can be seen if you disable the extension realurl (but that's another problem).

Comment: It's no realurl problem, I tested it.

Comment: okay I found it out: changed <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--><f:format.html>{CONTENT}</f:format.html><!--TYPO3SEARCH_end--> at my fluidtemplate to <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--><f:format.raw>{CONTENT}</f:format.raw><!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->

Comment: The search is working too now; but only the single view could be found. Is that normal?

Comment: consider using `{var->f:format.raw()}` instead of `<f:format.raw>{var}</f:format.raw>`.

Comment: In case your list action is not declared uncached it is not normal. BUT: in case you have a lot of news per day and you only show the top ten: if the list-page is cashed/indexed you will get wrong results as the news with the keyword might be scrolled off the list view meanwhile. Always index the full text instead of the teaser only.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ the listview shows circa 10-20 entries, manually set to archive to hide it. But to find the searched article, I will use a single view. Is there a way to add each article of the listview automatically to index without clicking on it?

Comment: Now I found out that it's working if I include the plugin per typoscript. But it's not working if I include it as content element -> plugin (with flexform settings)

Comment: Maybe this is the problem: If I include it via page content -> plugin, the plugin included as USER_INT and would not be cached/indexed. If I include it via typoscript as USER, it would be cached/indexed? So, if I'm right; how to include it as USER Object via page content -> plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working. There was something incorrect with the page itself, but disable cache wasn't active. So if someone else has the same problem; try inserting the plugin to another page and test it. I had to delete the page and create it again.